# Can't turn back to Homescreen (stacked with a Drawerscreen) with WillPopScope

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a language learning app and on my homepage there are specific topics like colors etc. which you can choose and a learning page (via JSON) opens. My problem is that I can't find a solution on how to get back to the Homescreen. It's a Stack.

here's the code from my HomePage class with the Stack:

```
  static const String id = 'home_page';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          DrawerScreen(),
          HomeScreen(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I already tried these solutions for my BackButton, but the app either crashes (when using the WillPopScope) or I'm getting a black screen (when using the

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Möchtest du das Quiz beenden?'),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Ja'),
                        onPressed: () =>
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, DrawerScreen.id),
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Nein'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                      ),
                    ]));
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 64.0, 8.0, 8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  BackButton(),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      AnimatedOpacity(
                        opacity: opacity1,
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            mydata[0][i.toString()],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 48.0,
                              fontFamily: "Circular",
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedOpacity(
                        opacity: opacity2,
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            mydata[1][i.toString()],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 48.0,
                              fontFamily: "Circular",
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: AbsorbPointer(
                  absorbing: disableAnswer,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        choicebutton1('a'),
                        choicebutton2('b'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back,
                        size: 30,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false)
```

remove the false

Comment: But that's false because the user pressed no. It says: Do you really want to leave the quiz? Yes -> Drawerscreen.id No -> Pop(false)